How can I get my organizations URN from API calls
I am using LinkedIn Developer to have an app that make posts to the company page. When trying to use api calls like https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=company-name I am given a 403 restricted error in postman.
I have tried using the headers of LinkedIn-Version : 202407 and X-Restli-Protocol-Version : 2.0.0 with my bearer token from the auth 2.0 tools in the linkedin developer app. Even someone who is a superadmin of the company page is being given 403 authorization errors when trying the same calls.
